# How to convert String into list of character while using lambda and map function?

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

```
x = 'WORLD'
y = lambda x: x * 2
map(y, x)
```

My actual output is

```
['WW', 'OO', 'RR', 'LL', 'DD']
```

But I want to print it as

```
'WORLDWORLD'
```

Comment: You're mapping each element.

Comment: In my case, I have the file path which I need to use it in lambda. If I call it using lambda, the character are iterating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
map(y, [x])
```

After 5 years now I could answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that strings  are iterable. So `map(y, x)` will apply the function `y` to each character (`W*2` gives you `WW`) and finally the function `map` returns the output  in form of a  list.

Comment: Is there a way to stop the string being iterable?

Answer (score 0):

You're using map, meaning you're applying the function to each item in the string, use:

```
y(x) # 'WORLD' * 2
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? I explained perfectly and a solution.

Answer (score 0):

This output is not surprising since strings are iterable objects in Python. Lambda function goes over each character and performs the multiplication.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).